# android uiautomator how to manage test method order

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-uiautomator

I am in the process of impelementing unit test via uiautomator. Right now i am facing the issue that i couldn`t manage test method order. Please help me how can i manage test methods sequence of running. It is not working by sequence of methods. Thanks in advance.

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    Log.i("Tage", "simpleTest");
    assertEquals(1, 1);
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    Log.i("Tage", "simpleTest");
    assertEquals(false, false);
}

@Test
public void thirdTest() {
    Log.i("Tage", "simpleTest");
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would not recommend having tests that depend on the execution order as they should be independent of each other, you can annotate you class with

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```

you can also use `DEFAULT` and `JVM` as sorters.